# How do I do a two-finger rotate gesture in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Flutter for my mobile app. My designer told me to use a "two-finger rotate" gesture for one of our screens. How do I implement this with Flutter?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm wrong. But it doesn't seems like this has been implemented yet.

Ideally you should create a `RotationGestureRecognizer` that extends `OneSequenceGestureRecognizer` ; which can then be added in `GestureDetector` (and submit a cool pull request). You can use `ScaleGestureRecognizer` as exemple.

You could also use `onPanDown`, `onPanUpdate` and `onPanEnd` to keep the position of all pointers. And use the `onPanUpdate` delta to calculate the rotation.

Comment: Added rotation tracking capability to ScaleGestureRecognizer. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17345